# How to get 3 conditions all matching in a PHP regex?

Tags: php, regex, expression

I am trying to write a regex and matches 3 conditions, and would return true if **all three** conditions are met.

Condition 1) `string starts with a "{"`

Condition 2) `string DOES NOT contain a space somewhere between brackets`

Condition 3 `string ends with a "}"`

So far I have come up with `^{|[ ]|}$`, which checks for a space.  But I need to make it match if there are **no spaces** between the brackets.  Also this will return true if the string starts with a `{` but doesn't end with a `}` and vise versa.  I've been messing with regex101.com, but can't figure the no spaces portion out.

Could someone explain how to match if something **does not** exist in the string?

Comment: With regex in general, instead of trying to avoid something, it's easier to describe all that is not what you want to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need

```
/^{\S*}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7eIaVk/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `{` - a literal `{`
- `\S*` - 0+ chars other than whitespace
- `}` - a literal `}`
- `$` - end of string.

For a general case, when you want to match *if something DOES NOT exist in the string*, you can bear in mind 2 approaches:

- 1) The  string that should be absent is a single char: use either a negated character class (e.g., `^[^;]*$` will match a string that has no `;` inside), or a "negative" shorthand character class (like here, `\S` is the reverse of `\s` and using `^\S*$` you match a string that has no whitespace)
- 2) The text that the string must not contain is a multicharacter string: then use lookarounds (e.g. the string should not contain `like`: `^(?!.*like).*$`, or even `^(?!.*like)`).

Comment: You explanation was really helpful ... Thanks!